# Validation Errors Despite No Validation Rule?

Tags: apex, trigger, validation, validation-rule

Uploading csv file using VF page. I am checking for not null of currency code else I am giving error.

But when I am using the below logic and uploading file it is directly taking to the validation error.

> "There were custom validation error(s) encountered while saving the affected record(s). The first validation error encountered was:
>
> Currency ISO Code: invalid currency code: ". "

**There are no validation rules on object!**

Comment: Can you please [edit] your post to specify the `sObjectType` you are trying to insert?

Comment: @AdrianLarson I edited my post with exact object what I am using and it is a custom object

Comment: Can you share the results of `Quote__c.CurrencyIsoCode.getDescribe().isRestrictedPicklist()`?

Comment: @AdrianLarson It is returning true when checked in debugs

Comment: I feel like this has gotten way off track. It may be better to revert back to your original question, which essentially asked *why* you were hitting a validation, then ask a separate question about *how* to resolve said validation.

Comment: I trimmed it back down to your core question, but don't worry. You can roll back or retrieve your code via the edit history.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some picklist fields have standard validation applied. See [Eliminate Picklist Clutter with Restricted Picklists](https://docs.releasenotes.salesforce.com/en-us/spring16/release-notes/rn_forcecom_general_restricted_picklists_beta.htm). You can determine if a picklist has this option enabled by examining its `DescribeFieldResult`:

```
Boolean isRestricted = Quote__c.CurrencyIsoCode.getDescribe().isRestrictedPicklist();
```

If the value is true, you can only use an option returned by the `getPicklistValues()` function:

```
List<Schema.PicklistEntry> validEntries =
    Quote__c.CurrencyIsoCode.getDescribe().getPicklistValues();
```

So you pre-validation, if you want invalid entries to not be a blocker, you could clean up your data using a `Set<String> whitelist`:

```
Set<String> validEntries = new Set<String>();
for (PicklistEntry entry : Quote__c.CurrencyIsoCode.getDescribe().getPicklistValues())
    validEntries.add(entry.getValue());

// ...

String isoCode = Filevalues[3];
if (validEntries.contains(isoCode))
    ob.CurrencyIsoCode = isoCode;
```

Comment: Thank for your answer I added the logic you provided and the entire uploading is failing even the currency iso codes are correct. In debug the  ob.CurrencyIsoCode is returning null

Comment: Yeah it could also be required...so you might want to add a fallback code. What is the failure message? Always provide the error message if you can. @Amar

Comment: Its is going to the else condition error as the code is null. That error message is showing on page. and even if I give USD in the file also it is taking null

Comment: Error : Error invalid currency/field1/field2

Comment: Is USD actually in `validEntries`?

Comment: Yes if before inserting the logic u provided and when currency values are filled properly then everything is working fine. If Currency code in csv file is empty then only it is giving validation error

Comment: Only if all fields are `null`, no? @Amar

Comment: sorry I didn't understand what you said.  But what i can say is if any one of the value is null it will enter that else error

Comment: Oh never mind, your if condition states that all four fields are *required*.

Comment: One more thing is currency picklist will be  USD - U.S.Dollar if I gave same value also it is taking as null

Comment: You should select a fallback value that is in `validEntries`...If the value is `USD - U.S. Dollar` then use that. Make sure you match on the result from `getValue()`.

Comment: sorry If I am not making sense I updated my code with what i did but still it is showing null in debug. but when I hard code the value what I gave in file it is working fine. but same value when I am giving from csv its giving else condition error  :(

Comment: I think I have sufficiently answered your initial question and you should ask a new one about strategies to handle this specific validation. Your original question allows for a clean, concise answer. This new topic not so much.

Comment: Thanks for your response I really appreciate your help :)